# Поиск в mongodb по нескольким ключам

Tags: php, mongodb

Подскажите, как на PHP выполнить запрос к MongoDB на поиск строки по нескольким ключам?

Документы имеют следующие ключи: subject, content, ticket, from

Важно, чтобы искалось не по полному совпадению, но и по частичному. Например, вводим запрос "**ello**" и нужно произвести поиск по всем указанным ключам. Результат: документы, в которых есть "h**ello**", "H**ello**World", "**ello**".

Я пробовал так:

```
$filter = [
            'content' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex('/^'.$str.'/', 'i')
        ];
        $search_mail = $mongo_db->mail->find($filter);
```

Но здесь поиск идет только по 1 ключу и очень медленно... (120 тыс. документов, время поиска около 4 секунд).

Comment: Regex не используют индексы. Там идет полный перебор, причем регуляркой. Ускорить это невозможно. Если нужен полнотекстовый поиск, то нужно использовать другие средства.

Comment: Для поиска по условию ИЛИ использовать [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/)